# Identify spatially contiguous clusters in raster data using kmeans

Tags: raster, r, clustering, machine-learning

I would like to cluster the cells of a raster object into k contiguous regions using kmeans. The number of regions, k, is known. Each cell has various geographical attributes, such as temperature, precipitation, elevation etc. And I need R to sort pixels into k groups (regions) using these cell values. With `stats::kmeans()` that is a fairly simple exercise. Unfortunately, this method does not create spatially contiguous clusters. Instead, each group consists of pixels spread all over the grid.

I expected this to be a common problem, but could not find any R function that solves it. There should be some package out there that can perform clustering under the restriction of spatial contiguity.

The method of choice here is kmeans because I know how many groups I need. Any other technique from the field of unsupervised learning that allows me to a priori set this quantity, is of course also welcome.

I asked this question on Stack Overflow before and received a recommendation to also post it here, as GIS might be a better fit than SO.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question above. This question is asking specifically about raster data and the other question is dealing with points.

Comment: If you think of a raster as nothing more than an array, they are basically the same thing. Raster cells are nothing more than an equally spaced array of X,Y with an assumed area denoted by the array spacing (ie., cell size). You can coerce a raster stack to a `SpatialGridDataFrame` or `SpatialPointsDataFrame` cluster the data held in the `@data` slot and then coerce the results back to a raster.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, I agree with Kartograaf. Those two questions are definitely no duplicates. A raster layer and spatial points are both spatial objects and both questions address unsupervised machine learning methods. I can convert a raster layer into equally spaced points. But this essentially misses the advantage of raster data when it comes to contiguity. The other question relying on differently spaced points has to arbitrarily define contiguity in terms of distance. Raster layers are matrix-like objects. With this tabular structure I can directly identify neighbors using Queen's or Rook's

Comment: case contiguity. This allows for conceptually different implementations in R. And I checked your the answer to the other post. It does not answer my question. So please re-open this discussion for further posts. There is no harm in leaving space for future contributions. The perfect answer may be yet to come. Thanks.

Comment: The available clustering algorithms, that are being discussed, all need coordinate input to account for the spatial constraint. This functionally means that regardless of raster input the data will be represented as an [x,y]z...i matrix, which are points with associated covariates. None of these approaches are leveraging the advantages of raster data in the way that you are thinking. At some point, functionally, coordinate vectors must be represented.

Comment: I reopened this post but reiterate that an answer is provided here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194873/clustering-geographical-data-based-on-point-location-and-associated-point-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the discussion above, I further explored the respective literature and found a very suitable algorithm addressing my question. The method is capable of defining neighborhood through rows and columns in the grid rather than distances between pixel centroids. I can directly choose between Queen's and Rook's case contiguity. Distances do not have to be included as explanatory variables and then weighted until regions are contiguous. The algorithm restricts regions to be spatially contiguous but does not necessarily make spatial distance or coordinates optimization variables. This provides increased flexibility in terms of region shapes.

The method is called SKATER (Spatial ‘K’luster Analysis by Tree Edge Removal) and is nicely outlined in the respective journal article by [Assuncao et al. (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1080/13658810600665111). The `spdep` package implements the algorithm into R. The package documentation, though, is rather brief and unintuitive. Fortunately, Luc Anselin provides an illustrative [tutorial](https://geodacenter.github.io/tutorials/spatial_cluster/skater.html) on how to to apply `spdep::skater()` to spatial polygons using French regions as an example. My subsequent code is an adaptation of his example to spatial data in raster structure.

As underlying data we use three raster layers, `r1`, `r2` and `r3`. They are all of equal extent and equal projection (equal-area Mollweide projection). They document the three explanatory variables, say surface temperature, precipitation and elevation, based on which want to assemble `k` regions.

```
# 1. Load packages
packs <- list("tidyverse", "raster", "spdep", "parallel")
lapply(packs, require, character.only = T)

# 2. Load raster layers using raster()

# 3. Define the number of regions (k + 1)
k <- 10

# 4. Merge explanatory variables in data frame
dat <- lapply(list(r1, r2, r3), values) %>%
   do.call(cbind, .) %>%
   as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
   magrittr::set_colnames(c("Temperature", "Precipitation", "Elevation"))

# 5. Set up parallel framework for faster computation (optional)
# For a non-parallel, single core execution skip steps 5 and 13
ncores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores, type = "PSOCK")
set.coresOption(ncores)
set.ClusterOption(cl)

# 6. Standardize variables
sdat <- scale(dat) %>%
   as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = F)

# 7. Create neighbor list object
raster_nb <- cell2nb(nrow(r1), ncol(r1), type = "queen")     # you can alternatively set contiguity to "rook"

# 8. Subset cells
# There are various reasons for which you might need to exclude some pixels to avoid errors in subsequent functions
# One example is missing values in your raster layers (e.g. due to water bodies)
complete_pixels <- which(complete.cases(sdat))
raster_nb <- subset.nb(raster_nb, 1:length(raster_nb) %in% complete_pixels)
sdat <- sdat[complete_pixels,]

# 9. Calculate dissimilarity between neighboring cells
lcosts <- nbcosts(raster_nb, sdat)

# 10. Calculate spatial weights based on dissimilarity between neighbors
raster_w <- nb2listw(raster_nb, lcosts, style = "B")

# 11. Obtain minimum spanning tree
raster_mst <- mstree(raster_w)

# 12. Run skater clustering algorithm
skater_clusters <- skater(raster_mst[,1:2], sdat, k)

# 13. Close parallel framework
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, but unfortunately it is unlikely to have a one-step solution. First perform your classification routine (unsupervised or supervised), then do a series of operations on the output to achieve the desired result.

Here are a couple good tools to try.

1. whitebox::majority_filter  - this will assign most frequently occurring value to cells using a moving window. First run it with a larger window size, then try running again with smaller window. https://rdrr.io/cran/whitebox/man/majority_filter.html
2. raster::clump - detects regions of connected cells. Set the direction to 8 so that all adjacent cells are considered. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-7/topics/clump

This link is a great reference for this type of analysis: https://geoscripting-wur.github.io/AdvancedRasterAnalysis/

Comment: Good advice but it does not address the multivariate aspect of the question. Unfortunately, because of the spatial congruence requirement, this becomes a spatial optimization problem along with multivarate clustering.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, @Kartograaf. However, Jeffrey is right. I need a method that accounts for the multivariate aspect. Does either of you have any idea how to combine the spatial optimization with the multivariate clustering?

Comment: I'll get an example up when I can, but until then you might have a look at this link: https://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/8_spatial_clusters/lab8.html

Answer (score 0):

I came across an R package that will help you do this, called "Clustgeo". https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustGeo/index.html

You can adjust the values for a parameter. "alpha", to control the weight placed on the spatial proximity of the cells to one another. The value can be adjusted between 0-1, where 0 represents no weight on the spatial data (only cluster based on data values). The higher you make alpha, the more weight will be placed on the spatial data (i.e. the clusters will become more contiguous).

To the best of my knowledge, there is not a straightforward way to determine what the ideal value for alpha is, so there is likely to be some trial and error involved. You might consider slowly increasing alpha until you see contiguous clusters and tune to find the minimum value where this is true.

original RGB image:

[image: RGB image]

pseudocolor representation:

[image]

Clusters in data space. Here the clusters are solely based on data values where alpha is zero and not at all based on data where alpha is one:

[image: data space]

Clusters in geographical space. Here you see the opposite, where clusters are not based on spatial component at low alpha and based entirely on spatial component at high alpha.

[image: geo space]

Here is the full script, it takes in a JPEG, reads it as a rasterlayer, then performs the clustering across a range of alphas and displays them so that you can compare the way the clusters change relative to the data and the geolocation of the pixels as the alpha changes. Adapted from the example here: https://github.com/MatthieuStigler/Misc/blob/master/spatial/spatial_segmentation_field_GeoClust_demo.md

```
#dependencies
library(raster)
##in case you need to install EBImage
# source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#   install.packages("BiocManager")
# BiocManager::install(version = "3.10")
library(EBImage)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(ClustGeo)
library(dplyr)

#path to image (replace file with your data)
r3 <- ('plants.JPG')

#read JPEG as raster
r <- raster(r3)

#create dataframe using pixel data from raster
ras_dat <- as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE) %>%  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(n_cell = 1:ncell(r)) %>% 
  select(n_cell, everything()) %>% 
  rename(value = plants)#change "plants" to your layer name

#introduce new functions
dist_rast_euclid <-  function(x)  {
  x %>% 
    xyFromCell(cell = 1:ncell(.))  %>% 
    dist() 
}
#HERE is where you want to change the number of clusters (k=)#
hclustgeo_df <-  function(D0, D1 = NULL, alpha, n_obs = TRUE, k = 5) {
  res <- hclustgeo(D0, D1, alpha = alpha) %>% 
    cutree(k=k) %>% 
    data_frame(cluster = .)
  if(n_obs) res <-  res %>% 
      mutate(n_obs =   1:nrow(.)) %>% 
      select(n_obs, everything())
  res

}

#caluclate distances between pixels
dat_dist <- dist(getValues(r))
geo_dist <-  dist_rast_euclid(r)

#compute cluster values for range of alphas (0 to 1 by 0.1)
res_alphas <- data_frame(alpha = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) %>% 
  mutate(alpha_name = paste("alpha", alpha, sep="_"),
         data = map(alpha, ~ hclustgeo_df(dat_dist, geo_dist, alpha = ., k=5)))

res_alphas_l <-  res_alphas %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  left_join(ras_dat, by = c("n_obs" = "n_cell")) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("alpha", "cluster"), as.factor) %>% 
  group_by(alpha, cluster) %>% 
  mutate(cluster_mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup()

res_alphas_l_dat <-  res_alphas_l %>% 
  filter(alpha %in% c(0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 1))

## show original image
pl_dat_orig <- res_alphas_l_dat %>% 
  filter(alpha ==0) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y= y, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  ggtitle("Original data")

## show clustering in data space (pixel values)
pl_clus_datSpace <- res_alphas_l_dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y= cluster, colour = cluster)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(alpha ~ .) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle("Cluster, in data space")

## show clustering in geo space (spatial proximity)
pl_clus_geoSpace <- res_alphas_l_dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y= y, fill = factor(cluster))) +
  geom_tile() +
  facet_grid(alpha ~ .) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle("Cluster, in geo-space")

pl_dat_orig
pl_clus_datSpace
pl_clus_geoSpace
```

Comment: Interesting approach but, your example makes it look like univariate segmentation.

Comment: Its not a univariate approach as long as the input for alpha is 0<a<1. If it is a=0 or a=1, then it would be univariate using the raster values or the spatial data respectively, otherwise it’s heirarchical. Please help me understand if I’m wrong. https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03897

Comment: Yes, it is spatially constrained agglomerative clustering similar to Birks & Gordon (1985) or Guo (2008). But, you are testing cluster solutions against a range of alphas (mixtures) and not clustering a spatial process against a set of covariates (eg., elevation, precipitation, slope). The OP basically wants to use something like k-means to cluster a set of variables ending up with spatial units representing the clustered data. I am not sure about the package implementation but, the Chavent et al., (2017) paper does allow for a multivariate clustering.

Comment: @Kartograaf, the gradually adjusted weights are an interesting way of addressing the issue. Thanks for providing a nice illustration based on the mechanism described in Luc Anselin's tutorial (your link in the post above) in R. I agree with Jeffrey in that there may be better solutions than this weighting approach. However, it is the best answer regarding my question I have come across so far. So, thanks again for your extensive example.