# Defining convex-hull of (clouds of) points using R?

Tags: r, point, polygonize, convex-hull

I have multiple (clouds of) points, and would like to take the outer envelope of these points. This will allow me to *polygonize* my points.

Using the convex-hull would help me, but in some cases, my shapes are not convex, and hence this convex-hull envelope contains large areas without any points. The question mark is a good example where one would not necessarily want a convex hull (from: [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi5766W1MjeAhWQFjQIHXKgDtsQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geosensor.net%2Fpapers%2Fgalton06.GISCIENCE.ppt&usg=AOvVaw3nJ_-pX8KcuKx5mBLgO-F6)):

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is there a **concept of non-convex** hull? How is this called, and conceptualized? I guess that while it is easy to define a convex hull (it is unique), it is difficult to conceptualize a non-convex hull, as this won't necessarily be unique, so any definition will be harder/involve some *free parameters*.
2. What are the **algorithms** to implement this, ideally in R?

Comment: see the alphahull package, or bare triangulation (e.g. geometry::delaunayn) and cull out large/long triangles - alphahull is a generalization of very raw methods

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I don't think asking about a concept as well as its implementation is that *broad*, many questions and answers follow (implicitly) that structure I feel

Comment: @mdsumner and there's actually a nice illustration of `alphahul` here: https://yihui.name/en/2010/04/alphahull-an-r-package-for-alpha-convex-hull/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are existing questions about clustering with good answers here [Find clusters of points based distance rule](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64392/find-clusters-of-points-based-distance-rule) and here [How to cluster spatial data in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/how-to-cluster-spatial-data-in-r).

For the actual hulling, the alg is called a 'concave hull', and package `concaveman` is your friend here. quick example with meuse:

```
library(sf)
library(concaveman)

data(meuse, package = "sp") # load data.frame from sp
meuse_sf = st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 28992)

split_soil <- split(meuse_sf, meuse_sf$soil)
hulls <- lapply(split_soil, concaveman)
hulls <- do.call('rbind', hulls)

plot(meuse_sf['soil'], pch = 20, cex = 1, reset = FALSE, axes = T)
plot(hulls, add = TRUE, border = 'grey70', col = NA)
```

[image]