# Cluster Analysis on spatial data on R?

Tags: r, clustering

I sampled a population of an insect in an area and got GPS points. Now I want to investigate if there are subpopulations within the pop using distance from points.
I have a dataset with coordinates data X and Y in this format (45.13904444, 6.990686111). The spatial reference system I use is WGS 84 UTM zone 32N EPSG:32632. 
I would like to do a cluster analysis according to the distance between points.

Anyone can give me a script to do this?

Comment: Perhaps these posts might help: [Clustering spatial data in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/clustering-spatial-data-in-r) and [Finding clusters of points based distance rule using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64392/finding-clusters-of-points-based-distance-rule-using-r)

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of "analysis" do you want? What's the fundamental question you are trying to answer? You can't just say "please give me a script to do cluster analysis" and expect to get what you need.

Comment: I resolved with @Joseph link on "Clustering spatial data in R?". Previously I tried a kNN approach but it doesn't work. Just for comprehension, I sampled a population of an insect in an area and got GPS points. Now I want to investigate if there are subpopulations within the pop using distance from points.

Comment: @VivianaDiPietro - I think it would be good if you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/332170/edit) your question to include the details of what you were investigating and then post an **answer** showing what you did and the script you used. This could help others in a similar situation :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say the kNN approach doesn't work? What did you try? What errors did you get? Is a kNN clustering better at answering the question you have about your data? What is that question?

Answer (score 3):

I resolve with this script:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(geosphere)

# example data from the thread
x <- c(-1.482156, -1.482318, -1.482129, -1.482880, -1.485735, -1.485770, -1.485913, -1.484275, -1.485866)
y <- c(54.90083, 54.90078, 54.90077, 54.90011, 54.89936, 54.89935, 54.89935, 54.89879, 54.89902)

# convert data to a SpatialPointsDataFrame object
xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
      matrix(c(x,y), ncol=2), data.frame(ID=seq(1:length(x))),
      proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))

# use the distm function to generate a geodesic distance matrix in meters
mdist <- distm(xy)

# cluster all points using a hierarchical clustering approach
hc <- hclust(as.dist(mdist), method="complete")

# define the distance threshold, in this case 40 m
d=40

# define clusters based on a tree "height" cutoff "d" and add them to the SpDataFrame
xy$clust <- cutree(hc, h=d)
```